# Why does solving for the inverse function leads $x$ to be a constant?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

I went down the wrong path in trying to show that; if $f(x)=ax+b$ then there is a $g(x)=dx+e$ such that $f(g(x)) = x$. This wrong path led me to a baffling result of x being a constant. Can anyone explain either my error or what it means?  Note that on my 2nd attempt I did derive $g(x)$, so that is not my question.  My question is what does the following mean?  How can x be a constant?

I did very simple substitution, just to see where it led me:

1. if $f(g(x)) = x$ then
2. $f(dx+e) = x$ and substituting;
3. $a(dx+e) +b = x$ and expanding
4. $adx +ae + b = x$ and grouping
5. $(ad-1)x = -ae - b$
6. $x = \frac{-ae-b}{ad-1}$ which is a constant

I know this is not how to get the inverse function.  I was able to figure that out.  But why do the above steps lead to an obviously impossible value for x?

Comment: Hint: Try an example where you know what $f$ and $g$ are. For example, say $f(x) = x-1$

Comment: Thank you.  I tried it and found the division by zero error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the reasoning is the same old division by zero. But this is very disguised.

Now, you start off with $f(g(x)) = x$, as an *equality of functions* : so  what this actually means, is that for every real number $r$ we have $f(g(r)) = r$.

Your manipulations led you to $(ad-1)x = -ae-b$, which continued to be an equality of functions.

---

At this point, you have divided both sides by $ad-1$. This has led to the functional equation $x = c$ for some constant $c$, which is a contradiction, and you feel you have done something wrong.

The truth is, you have *obtained by contradiction* that $ad-1 = 0$, because if *indeed* $ad-1 \neq0$ then the *functional* inequality $(6)$ would have held, which is not possible.

So no , $x$ *cannot be a constant*. Instead, the assumption that $ad-1\neq 0$ is *false* and has led you down this path, and once you tread it you know a contradiction awaits you. So that tells you $ad-1=0$.

Now, knowing that $ad-1 = 0$, from $(5)$ we get $ae+b = 0$. Thus, your objective of obtaining $d$ and $e$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ is achieved. Note that if $a= 0$ these constants can't be found.

---

Just want to add that if you want to derive $d$ and $e$ there's the easier method of substitution which you can use. As I mentioned earlier, a functional equality, upon substitution of appropriate numbers, becomes a numerical equality. So substitute numbers.

For example, suppose that $f(g(x)) = x$. Then substitute $x = 0$, to get $ae+b = 0$. Substitute $x = 1$ to get $a(d+e)+b = 1$, and solve these.

Comment: thank you!  I was hoping it was not some silly mistake and instead something I could learn from, and I did; to pay attention to obvious contradictions and use that to come to a conclusion. 
As you and SenZen suggested, I substituted the coefficients from g(x) and found that sure enough, $ad= 1$

Comment: @QueensDog you are welcome!